# How does the preamble synchronize other devices receiving clocks?

Tags: ethernet

As I know the preamble of an Ethernet packet consists of a 56-bit pattern of alternating 1 and 0 bits. But how exactly it helps the other devices to be synced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key for this is the IEEE 802.3 documents which define ethernet. There is an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/260965/what-is-ieee-802-3-ethernets-communication-type-synchronous-or-asynchronous) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) which addresses this.

From IEEE 802.3:

> 802.3-2008_section1.pdf
>   3.2.1 Preamble field The Preamble field is a 7-octet field that is used to allow the PLS circuitry to reach its steady-state
>   synchronization with the received packet’s timing (see 4.2.5).
>
> 4.2.5 Preamble generation In a LAN implementation, most of the Physical Layer components are allowed to provide valid output some
>   number of bit times after being presented valid input signals. Thus it
>   is necessary for a preamble to be sent before the start of data, to
>   allow the PLS circuitry to reach its steady state. Upon request by
>   TransmitLink- Mgmt to transmit the first bit of a new frame,
>   PhysicalSignalEncap shall first transmit the preamble, a bit sequence
>   used for physical medium stabilization and synchronization, followed
>   by the Start Frame Delimiter. If, while transmitting the preamble or
>   Start Frame Delimiter, the collision detect variable becomes true, any
>   remaining preamble and Start Frame Delimiter bits shall be sent. The
>   preamble pattern is: 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010 10101010
>   10101010 10101010 The bits are transmitted in order, from left to
>   right. The nature of the pattern is such that, for Manchester
>   encoding, it appears as a periodic waveform on the medium that enables
>   bit synchronization. It should be noted that the preamble ends with a
>   “0.”