# What is preamble in ethernet frame and why is it used?

Tags: switch, ethernet, network, networking

I've searched all over the internet and every say that it synchronize the receiver clocks. What does that mean?
Also I've seen another definition that preamble gives NIC time to realize a frame is coming. Is this even correct?
If so is a preamble a random generated value or a value generated to mean something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the preamble synchronize other devices receiving clocks?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24842/how-does-the-preamble-synchronize-other-devices-receiving-clocks) Strictly speaking, the preamble belongs to the physical layer, not to the data link layer's framing.

Comment: It answers but its too complex for my mind. THANKS THOUGH.

Comment: Assuming you're a beginner, you don't have to understand it from the beginning. Just keep in mind it's for bit-level and byte-level synchronization of the receiver.

Comment: Oh yes. Suure..

Comment: these are mostly level 1 issues. if you are learning layer2 and above, you don't really need to understand them.